# Ruby on Rails, Devise gem. How to remove current password when password is blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passwords, devise

Now I realise this topic has been covered many times before. However there did not appear to be a solution that wanted to make the current password field exempt only when the password in the database was blank.

I currently have the password required in my user model like:

```
def password_required?
  (authentications.empty? || !password.blank?) && super
end
```

Then I copied the update function across into my registrations controller:

```
def update
  if resource.update_with_password(params[resource_name])
    set_flash_message :notice, :updated
    sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
    redirect_to after_update_path_for(resource)
  else
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    render_with_scope :edit
  end
end
```

I just don't know how to go about ensuring that devise does not need a password when editing a blank password, do I also need to remove the current_password field from the view and do this?

```
<% if current_user.password_required? %>
  <p><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %></p>
<% end %>
<p><%= f.submit "Update" %></p>
```

Any suggestions would be great on this as I am sure I am overlooking something but I am still new to Rails on a whole. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay so I have finally figured this out!

Add the following to your class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

```
def update
  if resource.update_with_password(params[resource_name])
    set_flash_message :notice, :updated
    sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
    redirect_to after_update_path_for(resource)
  else
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    render_with_scope :edit
  end
end
```

Then the following to your User model:

```
def update_with_password(params={})
  current_password = params.delete(:current_password) if !params[:current_password].blank?

  if params[:password].blank?
    params.delete(:password)
    params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
  end

  result = if has_no_password?  || valid_password?(current_password)
    update_attributes(params) 
  else
    self.errors.add(:current_password, current_password.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
    self.attributes = params
    false
  end

  clean_up_passwords
  result
end

def has_no_password?
  self.encrypted_password.blank?
end
```

The only thing I was slightly confused about is that in the edit view:

```
<% if !current_user.has_no_password? %>
```

I wrapped it in that if, I would have thought it would have been:

```
<% if current_user.has_no_password? %>
```

If anyone can see anything to improve my code or a different, more efficient way let me know!

Comment: `current_user.has_no_password?` returns `true` if there isn't a password, thus the if statement executes its block.  You're using negative language to validate that statement... you should write `unless current_user.has_no_password?`, but it still reads funny.  It's an easier read if you do `current_user.has_password?` and set the definition to return `self.encrypted_password.present?` (I realize this has been discussed below, but this belongs in the comments, and I've given an alternate, more readable solution)

Comment: I used this as the basis for something else and it pretty much works. Only change: I had to remove the `if !params[:current_password].blank?` to avoid getting mass-assignment errors, because current password was getting set to `""` (and therefore `blank? == true`) so wasn't getting deleted from params, and then `update_attributes(params)` tried up update the user record with `:current_password => ""` - obviously fails since `current_password` isn't an attribute on user... Maybe I've got the wrong end of the stick though? Also aren't the `self`s redundant?

Comment: I tried this solution, I got Can't mass-assign protected attributes: current_password

Comment: @wulftone I think by that rationale, you'd end up creating two versions of methods every time for all Boolean returning methods. Done people hate unless. Some people hate negatives. Is your using a method primarily for when it's one Boolean result, then by all means name it so that it's true most of the time. But if you use both results, then I think defining a new method is the most cumbersome.

Answer (score 3):

Another very minor change on requiring the current password field or not: my goal is never require a current password unless they are updating their password.  for oauth'ed accounts, I check for the facebook id in the view, and don't display the password fields at all.

In the registrations controller:

```
Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def update

self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)

   if resource.update_with_password(params[resource_name])
     set_flash_message :notice, :updated if is_navigational_format?
     sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
     respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
   else
     clean_up_passwords(resource)
     respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :edit }
   end


end
```

In User.rb, I use update_with_password, and then call verify_password_and_update only if the user has entered something in the password field from the view.  Otherwise, I clear the current password param and call update_without_password (this method is built in to devise now as well):

```
#to remove the current password check if updating a profile originally gotten via oauth (fb, twitter)


  def update_with_password(params={})
    if params[:password].blank?
      params.delete(:current_password)
      self.update_without_password(params)
    else
      self.verify_password_and_update(params)
    end
  end

  def update_without_password(params={})

    params.delete(:password)
    params.delete(:password_confirmation)
    result = update_attributes(params)
    clean_up_passwords
    result
  end
  def verify_password_and_update(params)
    #devises' update_with_password 
    # https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb
    current_password = params.delete(:current_password)

    if params[:password].blank?
      params.delete(:password)
      params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
    end

    result = if valid_password?(current_password)
      update_attributes(params)
    else
      self.attributes = params
      self.valid?
      self.errors.add(:current_password, current_password.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
      false
    end

    clean_up_passwords
    result
  end
```

Comment: thanks so much for sharing your code. i was stuck doing this for a while and seeing your code helped = )